# Queue not looping, and terminates early?

Tags: java, arrays, queue

Im trying to create an enhanced game of pig, where the user can roll a user entered number of dice. if all the dice rolled were a one, then you lose your bank points, if on of them is one, you get no points and your bank is safe. otherwise, you get to bank the points you rolled. I'm trying to loop through a queue in order for each player to get their turn, but it just loops the same person in the queue asking for how many dice the player wants to roll, then gets a result and terminates. What am i doing wrong here?

Also here's the current console output:

[image]

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;   
import javax.lang.model.element.Element;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Queue;
import java.util.Random;

public class EnhancedGameOfPig {
    static int count;

    static int roll() {
        return (int) (6.0 * Math.random()) + 1;
    }

    public static void play() {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        Queue<Player> myQueue = new LinkedList<Player>();
        System.out.println("How many players are there? (2-10 Max)");
        int numOfPlayers = sc.nextInt();
        sc.nextLine();
        for (int i =0; i < numOfPlayers; i++) { // creates specified number of
                                                    // players and adds
                                                    // them to a queue
            System.out.println("What is your name player " + (i+1) + "?");
            String playerName = sc.nextLine();
            Player player = new Player(playerName, 0);
            myQueue.add(player);
        }

        System.out.println("How many points would you like to play to, to win?"); // sets
                                                                                    // the
                                                                                    // number
                                                                                    // of
                                                                                    // points
                                                                                    // required
                                                                                    // to
                                                                                    // win
                                                                                    // the
                                                                                    // game
        int maxPoints = sc.nextInt();
        sc.nextLine();

        for (Player e : myQueue) {
            System.out.println("How many dice would you like to roll " + myQueue.peek().getPlayerName() + " ?");
            int numofDice = sc.nextInt();
            sc.nextLine();
            int[] diceArray = new int[numofDice]; // creates an array to hold
                                                    // values of each dice roll
            for (int i = 0; i <= numofDice-1; i++) {
                diceArray[i] = roll(); // rolls dice and adds dice roll values
                                        // to array
                if (diceArray[i] == 1) {
                    count++;
                }
            }
            int first = diceArray[0]; // looks at first value of array
            for (int element : diceArray) {
                if (element == first && first == 1) { // checks to see if all
                                                        // rolls were 1's
                    System.out.println("All of the dice you rolled were ones! You loose all your banked points!");
                    myQueue.peek().setBankedPoints(0);
                    break;
                }

            }
            if (count == 1) {
                System.out.println("You rolled a one, so you don't get any points. Sorry!");
            } else {
                int sum = IntStream.of(diceArray).sum();
                System.out.println(sum + " points have been added to your bank!");
                myQueue.peek().bankedPoints += sum;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In your for-each loop `for(Player e : myQueue)` change `myQueue.peek().getPlayerName()` to `e.getPlayerName()`, your for loop is correctly looping through `myQueue` once before your `main` method is finished

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your loop control iterates through each player in the queue.

```
for (Player e : myQueue) {
```

But throughout your loop body your refer only to first player in the queue, with `myQueue.peek()`. For example:

```
System.out.println("How many dice would you like to roll " 
   + myQueue.peek().getPlayerName() + " ?");
```

The `peek()` method returns the first player in the queue, but you're trying to affect the player `e`. You can address this problem by using `e` instead of `myQueue.peek()`, throughout the loop body.

Comment: what would be a more appropriate method call. im new to queues sorry heh

Comment: If you want to refer to the player `e`, you don't need a method call. You already have a reference to that player -- it's `e`.

Comment: so e.peek( ) or myQueue.e?

Comment: Use `e` where you use `myQueue().peek()`.  Also note that if you wish to play to `maxPoints`, you may want to put a loop around the for loop (try a `while(highestScore < maxPoints)` loop and calculate `highestScore`)

Comment: Neither `e.peek()` nor `myQueue.e`. Just `e`. The contents of the queue are references to Player objects. The loop is iterating through those references. The variable `e` points to the same object as one of the references in the queue.